# Evaluating $\cos\frac{17\pi}{18} \cos\frac{7\pi}{9}+ \sin\frac{17\pi}{18} \sin\frac{7\pi}{9}$ with a sum or difference formula

Tags: trigonometry

> Use a sum or difference formula to find the exact value of the following:
>
> $$\cos\frac{17\pi}{18} \cos\frac{7\pi}{9}+ \sin\frac{17\pi}{18} \sin\frac{7\pi}{9}$$

The answer I got for this was $0.8660254$. Please let me know if my answer is correct.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve formatting; I hope I preserved your intent

Answer (score 2):

Yes; using the difference formula, it's $\cos\left(\dfrac{17\pi}{18}-\dfrac{14\pi}{18}\right)=\cos
\left(\dfrac\pi6\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt3}2.$

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I don't why I didn't think to keep it in radical and fraction form.